# Internet Explorer not working with here maps api version 3.1

Tags: javascript, html, here-api

I am trying make Here Maps working on **internet explorer 11**. I have added the legacy modules mentioned here: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/migration.html 
and also I have changed the engine type to P2D. On chrome, firefox and Edge browsers everything is working just fine, but on IE11 nothing shows and I am getting an error in console: "Unable to get property 'util' of undefined or null reference
mapsjs-service-legacy.js (7,1)".

Mentioned line looks like this `H.service.util.eval(<Some other code>);` and 
it seems like despite the fact the `H` object is imported it does not have a field named `service`.

My imports looks like this:

```xml
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.css" />
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-core-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type=" text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service-legacy.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
```

And JS code for map initialization:

```js
var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    apikey: api_key
});
var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();

var map = new H.Map(mapDiv,
    defaultLayers.raster.normal.map,{
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: 50, lng:5},
        engineType: H.map.render.RenderEngine.EngineType.P2D,
        pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio || 1

});
```

Anyone knows where the problem is and what should I change?

Comment: I tried with two different versions of IE11 and both work fine with 3.1 API. Could you please share like error message/stack you get?

Comment: It happens I had additional space inside import. It was my fault. Sorry for taking your time and thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that it's solved. Sure, no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was wrong. It was additional space in `type=" text/javascript` inside `mapsjs-service.js` import:

```
<script src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.1/mapsjs-service.js" type=" text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Removing that space solved all my issues.